# Detectar número entero teniendo sólo ceros después del punto

Tags: python, float, decimal

intento detectar si los números son int o float o no, y teniendo un número como 2.0, que es entero, no consigo crear un programa que lo detecte como tal, aún siendo un cero lo que hay a la derecha del punto lo detecta como float. Y no soy yo el que genera ese número es el ordenador después de una operación, y aunque el resultado sea entero lo detecta como decimal. Obviamente no sirven trucos como transformarlo a entero. Si alguien tiene una idea se lo agradecería muchísimo de verdad.

```
num=10
div=num-5
re=(num/div)
print(re)
print(str(re).isdigit())
```

En este caso el output sería:

```
2.0
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
def es_entero(valor):
    return not valor % 1
```

La operación modulo (`%`) nos da el resto de la división. El resto de algo dividido por 1 es su parte fraccionario. Si tiene parte fraccionaria, no es entero.

**Demo**

```
def es_entero(valor):
        return not valor % 1

tests = [0, 1, 1.0, 1.01, 2.99]
for test in tests:
    print(test, es_entero(test))
```

produce:

```
0 True
1 True
1.0 True
1.01 False
2.99 False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias se lo agradezco