# ¿Como pasar un string a un decimal si tiene un número decimal mayor que 0, o pasar a entero si tiene un numero decimal igual a 0?

Tags: python, string, decimal

Primeramente tengo este código que me deja escribir un valor string, y ahora necesito saber como puedo pasarlo a entero si el string tiene un decimal 0, o como pasarlo a flotante si el string tiene un decimal mayor que 0.

```html
números = [1, 2]
valores = []
for i in números:
    print("Digite el número: ", i)
    x = input()
    valores.append(x)

Num1, Num2 = valores
    
Suma = Num1 + Num2
Resta = Num1 - Num2
Mult = Num1 * Num2
Div = Num1 / Num2

print(f"La suma de los 2 números es: {Suma}")
print(f"La resta de los 2 números es: {Resta}")
print(f"La multiplicación de los 2 números es: {Mult}")
print(f"La división de los 2 números es: {Div}")
```

Comment: Le quite el valor int donde dice x = input(), antes de quitarselo estaba así x = int(input()), hice eso para saber como pasar de un string a un entero si su decimal es 0 o pasar de un string a un flotante si su decimal es mayor que 0.

Answer (score 2):

Esta función recibe una cadena numérica y retorna su valor como objeto de tipo `int`, a menos que tenga una parte decimal distinta de cero, en cuyo caso retorna `float`.

```
def convertir_numero(valor):
    temp = float(valor)
    if temp % 1:
        return temp
    else:
        return int(temp)
```

La operación modulo `temp % 1` produce la parte fraccionaria del valor. Si no tiene parte fraccionaria, o si esta es cero, retorna cero.

**Demo**

```
def convertir_numero(valor):
    temp = float(valor)
    if temp % 1:
        return temp
    else:
        return int(temp)

tests = ["1", "2.0", "3.1", "-2.9", "-10", "1e10", "1.0e12", "1.1e-1"]

for test in tests:
    conv = convertir_numero(test)
    print(test, conv, type(conv))
```

produce

```
1 1 <class 'int'>
2.0 2 <class 'int'>
3.1 3.1 <class 'float'>
-2.9 -2.9 <class 'float'>
-10 -10 <class 'int'>
1e10 10000000000 <class 'int'>
1.0e12 1000000000000 <class 'int'>
1.1e-1 0.11 <class 'float'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Interesante tu comentario también funcionaria

Answer (score 2):

Creo que el enfoque de la pregunta no es correcto.

A la vista de un comentario que has puesto en una respuesta previa:

> Pero y si fuera un numero como 45, entonces lo que pasaria seria que me quedara 45.0 y como hago para que no me muestre ese número, sino que me muestre solo el 45 como entero.

parece que tu problema no es tanto que los datos internamente se almacenen como de tipo `int` o de tipo `float`, sino que al mostrarse por pantalla se muestren sin decimales en el caso en que la parte decimal sea 0, o bien con decimales cuando la parte decimal es distinta de cero.

Si estoy en lo correcto en mi interpretación, no arreglas el problema tratando los datos como `int` o  `float` en el momento de su lectura ya que imagina por ejemplo que el usuario introduce `1.5` y `2.5`. En ese caso ambos serían `float`, por lo que el resultado sería también un `float` pero en este caso ese resultado es un "número redondo" (`4.0`) y tú querrías que se mostrara `4`.

No hay que confundir el tipo de un dato con como se muestra al imprimirlo. Si lo que quieres es cambiar cómo se muestra, debes usar una cadena de formato apropiada. En cuanto al tipo del dato creo que lo más correcto en este caso sería tratar todos como `float`, pues no tiene mucho sentido tampoco que uno de los datos sea `int` y el otro sea `float` (ya que al sumarlos, restarlos o multiplicarlos, el `int` sería convertido a `float` por Python para poder realizar la operación).

La solución que propongo por tanto es tratar todos los datos como `float` y modificar la forma en que los imprimes al final, para usar el formato `"g"` que indica que se debe mostrar el resultado **con el mínimo posible** de decimales. Así, si el resultado es `4.0` se mostrará `4`.

Este sería por tanto el código tal como lo has escrito tú, pero modificado según mi enfoque:

```
números = [1, 2]
valores = []
for i in números:
    print("Digite el número: ", i)
    x = input()
    valores.append(float(x))

Num1, Num2 = valores
    
Suma = Num1 + Num2
Resta = Num1 - Num2
Mult = Num1 * Num2
Div = Num1 / Num2

print(f"La suma de los 2 números es: {Suma:g}")
print(f"La resta de los 2 números es: {Resta:g}")
print(f"La multiplicación de los 2 números es: {Mult:g}")
print(f"La división de los 2 números es: {Div:g}")
```

### Ampliación

Ya fuera de lo que es la pregunta, el código podría mejorarse ligeramente en la parte en que lees los números cambiando la lista `números` por un contador, y protegiendo la entrada con un `try/except` por si el usuario teclea algo que no es interpretable como número (forzando en ese caso a que repita la entrada):

```
valores = []
i = 1
while i <= 2:
    try:
      x = float(input(f"Digite el número {i}: "))
      valores.append(x) 
      i += 1
    except ValueError:
      print("El dato no es un número válido. Introdúzcalo de nuevo.")
```

Comment: Te quedo excelente la respuesta sigue asi mejorando . Una pregunta me puedes dejar un enlace para saber mejor como usar "g"?

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta era con la funcion `isdigit`

```
números = [1, 2]
valores = []
for i in números:
    print("Digite el número: ", i)
    x = input()
    valores.append(x)

Num1, Num2 = valores

if Num1.isdigit() == False:
    Num1 = float(Num1)

if float(Num1)%1 == 0:
    Num1 = int(Num1)

if Num2.isdigit() == False:
    Num2 = float(Num2)

if float(Num2)%1 == 0:
    Num2 = int(Num2)

Suma = Num1 + Num2
Resta = Num1 - Num2
Mult = Num1 * Num2
Div = Num1 / Num2

if str(Suma).isdigit() == True:
    print(f"La suma de los 2 números es: {Suma}")

if str(Suma).isdigit() == False:
    print(f"La suma de los 2 números es: " + "{:.2f}".format(Suma))
    
if str(Resta).isdigit() == True:
    print(f"La resta de los 2 números es: {Resta}")

if str(Resta).isdigit() == False:
    print(f"La resta de los 2 números es: " + "{:.2f}".format(Resta))
    
if str(Mult).isdigit() == True:
    print(f"La multiplicación de los 2 números es: {Mult}")

if str(Mult).isdigit() == False:
    print(f"La multiplicación de los 2 números es: " + "{:.2f}".format(Mult))

if str(Div).isdigit() == True:
    print(f"La división de los 2 números es: {Div}")

if str(Div).isdigit() == False:
    print(f"La división de los 2 números es: " + "{:.3f}".format(Div))
```

Para que sepan usar `.isdigit()` aqui dejo otro link.
[Detectar número entero teniendo sólo ceros después del punto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/484496/detectar-n%c3%bamero-entero-teniendo-s%c3%b3lo-ceros-despu%c3%a9s-del-punto)

Y si quieren saber porque uso `.format()` les dejo este link.

[Limitar dígitos en un número periódico en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236945/limitar-d%C3%ADgitos-en-un-n%C3%BAmero-peri%C3%B3dico-en-python)

Comment: Los snipets se usan solo con código html, css y js

Answer (score -2):

Buenas en vez de utilizar  int() de entero utiliza float() para decimales.

```
números = [1, 2]
valores = []
for i in números:
  print("Digite el número: ", i)
  x = float(input())
  valores.append(x)

Num1, Num2 = valores

Suma = Num1 + Num2
Resta = Num1 - Num2
Mult = Num1 * Num2
Div = Num1 / Num2
if Suma==int(Suma):
  Suma=int(Suma)
if Resta==int(Resta):
  Resta=int(Resta)
if Mult==int(Mult):
  Mult=int(Mult)
if Div==int(Div):
  Div=int(Div)

print(f"La suma de los 2 números es: {Suma}")
print(f"La resta de los 2 números es: {Resta}")
print(f"La multiplicación de los 2 números es: {Mult}")
print(f"La división de los 2 números es: {Div}")
```

En la división estaría bien poner una excepción de DivisionError:
Espero sea esto que buscas

Comment: Pero y si fuera un numero como 45, entonces lo que pasaria seria que me quedara 45.0 y como hago para que no me muestre ese número, sino que me muestre solo el 45 como entero. Otra cosa es que sea 45.3, ahi si quiero que me lo muestre com flotante pero tu hicistes que solamente fueran flotantes todos.

Comment: El OP quiere generar objetos de la clase `int` o `float`, según sea el caso. Esta respuesta convierte todo a `float`.

Comment: Mira a ver si con los condicionales te sirve